# Error:Must have one-pixel frame that is either transparent or white in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have just imported a project from eclipse to Android studio. Almost for every second image , android studio is giving the following error.

```
Error:Must have one-pixel frame that is either transparent or white.
```

I am trying to edit my images for last few hours, but couldn't do it. Can anyone guide me whats the best solution for it.

Why its in only Android Studio why not in Eclipse.

Comment: I assume this has something to do with 9-patch. Do your images end with .9.png?

Comment: yup, almost every image, and perhaps every image which is showing error

Comment: i am facing same problem can you please guide me? android studio not telling which image is corrupt

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is shown because you're trying to edit 9-Patch images that don't have the appropriate 1-pixel border.

Android uses an image format called 9-Patch which allows you to define stretchable areas in an image (you can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)). To fix your problem, either add an outer 1-pixel thick transparent frame to your png images or simply rename them from **.9.png** files to **.png** files

Comment: Well, if the images aren't really 9-Patch images, changing their extension to the correct one is pretty much the solution

Comment: i am getting same error and android studio wont telling which image is corrupt how can i detect that please?