# Gradle Sync Failed for app imported from ADT to Studio: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: android, android-studio

I imported my ADT project containing AndroidManifest.xml into Android Studio.

It shows Gradle Sync failure as below:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:extractProguardFiles
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportPaletteV72400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2510Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2510Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2510Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2510Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2510Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132510Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42510Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAwareness1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCastFramework1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesClearcut1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGass1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesInstantapps1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlaces1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanager1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerApi1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerV4Impl1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAppindexing1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseConfig1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCrash1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabase1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabaseConnection1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseMessaging1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorage1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorageCommon1001Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:237)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:161)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:88)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:245)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:232)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:268)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataMerger.mergeData(DataMerger.java:301)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceMerger.mergeData(ResourceMerger.java:410)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:154)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:264)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v1.AaptV1.lambda$compile$0(AaptV1.java:446)
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.out(AaptProcess.java:284)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.out(AaptProcess.java:215)
    at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$2.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:143)


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 14.281 secs
```

Also attached is a snapshot of my app's build.gradle file.

[image]

Things I tried:

1. Though I don't see any crushing error, still I shortened my project path.
2. I also tried giving a smaller build path by changing build.dir attribute in allProjects{} in project's root build.gradle as follows

buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"

3. I removed google play services from sdk manager. Docs say that Google Repository is sufficient. Initially I had installed both play services as well as google repository, same problem was occuring. Later, I removed play services.
4. I removed android-support-v13.jar from libs folder and added this entry in build.gradle - compile "com.android.support:support-v13:25.1.0".
5. I put joda sources jar as mentioned in build.gradle in libs folder manually as Studio didn't do it.

Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: possible a corrupt .9.png or you might have manually renamed a .jpg or .bmp to a .png?  :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED  error ive faced almost always was related to some issue with the resources. also which version gradle are you using?

Comment: @ViVekH I am using gradle version - 2.14.1 Android plugin version - 2.2.3. Regarding corrupt .9.png, I can say that I imported a perfectly working project from ADT. But, still if this error is always related to some issue in resources, I will check each png.

Comment: @ViVekH Also, I have  a large number of resources. As exception is not specifying any particular name, is there any easier way to find out a corrupt png?

Comment: give this a try http://stackoverflow.com/a/41458607/3518278

Comment: @ViVekH, I followed the link that you mentioned. In particular, to see full log messages, I followed the comment given by user Dot1q84 and modified 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3' to 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2' in my project gradle, and rebuilt the project. Then I got exact error messages where a number of my .9.png files were malformed. I am in the process of removing and correcting those. I will update here, if everything works fine after that. Thanks a lot for your pointer!

Comment: Resolved. I renamed .9.png files to .png and build was successful. I have added a formal answer as well summarizing all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two issues:
1. I was not able to see the complete error log(Read my earlier comments).
2. There were issues in my resources as I was getting execution failure for task :app:mergeDebugResources
After changing the entry in build.gradle(Project) for classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3' to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2', which was necessary to see the complete log of error messages(due to a possible bug in 2.2.3), I could see the list of malformed .9.png files in my drawable folders.
To resolve those issues, I renamed my .9.png files to just .png files. This resolved the AAPT error coming for my .9.png files "Must have one-pixel frame that is either transparent or white". 
 For reference see [Error:Must have one-pixel frame that is either transparent or white in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602149/errormust-have-one-pixel-frame-that-is-either-transparent-or-white-in-android-s)

Answer (score 0):

Change `minify enabled` to `false`.

Comment: Hi, I changed minify enabled to false. It is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

include this inside your android tag in build.gradle

```
   packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
```

Comment: 1) Are you guessing based on what works for you? 2) You can edit your other post.